# Cut out the start and end of a .mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, cut

I have been using ffmpeg to remove the first 5 seconds of a video clip with the following code.

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -ss 05 -acodec copy -vcodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause

Is there a way to remove the first 5 sec along with the last 8 seconds of the .mp4 file?

Answer (score 0):

If I have 1 minute (60 seconds) clip it will be something like:
from  00:00:00 - 00:01:00 to

> ```
> -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:55
> ```

more info: [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)